Medical service Provider-Recipient relations where to ask
I want to ask a question about Provider-Recipient relations in medical services (whether asking about the safety of a dosage feels like double-guessing and what should someone do as a prudent, alert, health conscious medical service recipient).
I am open about my experiences.
My parents neglected me when I complained of headaches, diplopia, vomits.
After a diagnostic odyssey of 7 years I was diagnosed with brain cancer (that I was probably born with) 11 years ago
My maternal aunt (a neurologist) prescibed me with antideppressants when I was 6 years old and 10 years later as soon as I was out of the hospital she gave me antideppresssants again (without even telling my father or even the neurosurgeon). She lied to me and told me it was for gastroprotection. At 16 I didn't know fluoxetine was an antidepressant. I didn't reach out or ask for the drug leaflet. I was in the bed of my house having just been out of the hell I was for 33 days. Blind from one eye and deaf from the same side (it was obvious that the surgery would affect the vesibulocochlear nerve too). Bound to the bed and at the mercy of my family. Only my aunt knew I was taking antidepressants. For 11 years I am fighting with liver problems, hypertransaminemia (particularly γgt), hypoglobulinemia, problems with prothrombin time, erythrocyte sedimentation rate, plasminogen, fibrinogen, LDH, CRP. I stopped (another neurologist told me so) because the antideppressants were causing (at least aggravating the oncogenic epilepsy) epileptic seizures and I am getting (constantly) better.
While in the hospital (I was 16) I had nurses denying me a bedpan and forcing me to use diapers and a catheter so I can lessen their workload in the ICU.
From the pediatric ICU I was moved to an adult ICU to make room for a baby (the neurosurgeon vetted it the next day but 1 day was enough for me to get lots of infections).
I am legally blind in the right eye because the multiple cranial nerves palsies were ignored (oculomotor,trochlear, trigeminal, abducens, facial) and it left me with corneal edema (scaring).
I was bound to the wheelchair far longer that I should because the doctors particularly my neurologist aunt were dismissive (saying that I don't want to walk I didn't need a physiatrist).
More that a year after the surgery a physiatrist saw me (for the first time) and the improvements with botulinum toxic were evident immediately.
People know of my experiences and make conjectures that I have trust issues. I don't think I have trust issues even with my past experiences it is just that trust is not a blank cheque (anything goes I am subject to everything so that I can demonstrate my trust). I am afraid to ask questions on the safety (I am afraid of the consequences).
I already had a University Diagnostic Center (I have had over 40 MRI these 11 years) deny me my needed MRI spectroscopies. Because I asked what could possibly be the protocols for sterilizing plastic (that even pharmaceuticals call them one use) emesis basins (inox ones cost a hundred times more, are sold on a per unit basis instead of boxes with 4 hundred inside) and I want my father (since I am visually disabled even if I am nearing 28) to be near me to look at the needle and taking care that they open it in front of him (as opposed to making a mistake a reusing the one they used in a previous patient).
I found another diagnostic center in an anticancer hospital.
There they told me that I needed 30mmol of Gadobutrol. But I am 88-90 kiloes not 100.
I know that there are protocols that need 0.2 even 0.3 mmol/kg
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23681501/
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/medicine-and-dentistry/gadobutrol
But 0.3 and 0.341 are not the same number. I am already under 750mg of Levetiracetam.
When I voiced my concerns and asked whether 30ml is a safe dose:
The radiation oncologist told me that if I don't feel safe I should look someplace else. And that everyone loves me.
The (imaging) radiologist told me that 2-3 ml are lost with the power injector and let us not discuss it perpetually.
My question would be
Does asking about the safety of a medical procedure or a drug dosage feel to the doctor like second-guessing, what should someone do as a prudent, alert, health conscious medical service recipient?
Would this question be on topic in Interpersonal Skills; are the relations of Provider-Recipient in medical services on topic? Could I ask in another SE.site?
What should the tags be, I am thinking of Confict Aversion (avoiding making the doctor feel you are second guessing them), Awkard Situation (since the Confict between Second-Guessing and Informed Consent is awkard), Politeness (since I am trying to get informed without making them feel I am second-guessing them), etiquette (for the same reason probably there is a standard way to ask), and conflicts (there is a conflict between Second-Guessing and Informed Consent).
**I don't know if I should post a separate question. If so please rollback and I will post a new question. I think it is just alternative wording
I understand from https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/didnt-the-edit-make-my-point-clear#comment13703_4109
A question on how to do something is On Topic.
And that I basically what I would like to ask (I can change the phrasing and be more direct).**

I want to ask how can I get information from my physician with the
questions I am asking without making it seem like I am questioning
their competency.

I don't want to ask about the specific doctor's feelings. I am worried that my behavior may seem impolite, second-guessing, questioning their competency (to any doctor maybe even laypeople). There is a specific tag "approach" in the Main Site. I want to get information for my healthcare without appearing that I am questioning their competency. I want to know the correct approach.


Does asking about the safety of a medical procedure or a drug dosage feel to the doctor like second-guessing, what should someone do as a prudent, alert, health conscious medical service recipient?

This won't be on-topic. The first part about guessing the doctor's feelings is primarily opinion based, any question asking us about what someone else's feelings would be, is. While it most often comes to this site in the form of "does she love me", this is just as opinion based.
The second part is a "what should I do" question , which are specifically listed in /help/on-topic as not being suitable for this site.
So no, your question would not fit on this site, and I don't see any other SE site taking it either.

I don't want to ask about the specific doctor's feelings. I am worried that my behavior may seem impolite, second-guessing, questioning their competency (to any doctor maybe even laypeople). There is a specific tag "approach" in the Main Site. I want to get information for my healthcare without appearing that I am questioning their competency. I want to know the correct approach.

Please advice me on what I call an alternative wording (not an entirely different question) should I roll back and post a new question or is it a proper improvement of the question?
